# GLSL errors accessing float array with variable as index

Tags: glsl

I'm making a shader in [glsl.heroku.com](http://glsl.heroku.com) and when I try to access an array of floats declared like this:

```
float colors[200];
```

in this way:

```
int i=function();
float color=colors[i];
```

it doesn't compile, a "compiled with errors" error appears.
Is this because glsl doesn't allow it or is it a heroku specific problem? In the case it's the former, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer (well, the user kaoD solved it). heroku uses WebGL, which uses OpenGL ES 2.0, and it doesn't treat arrays as normal arrays, but more like separated variables, so it can't access them at runtime unless it's with a constant index.